# save admin form and redirect back url in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, save, admin-controller

I have create admin sales grid. All is working fine.
And i have added one link in order view page.
This link click redirect custom admin form.
And Finally i want to save custom admin form. And  redirect order view page backurl

View edit link in order view section :-

[image]

And then click edit link go to custom admin form.And custom admin form save after redirect order view page.

Order view page URL :- **http://127.0.0.1/mag233/admin/sales/order/view/order_id/2/**

Custom admin form URL :- **http://127.0.0.1/mag233/admin/editfrom/index/index/order_id/2/**

> And then custom admin form save after come back order view page.

Here is my save controller code :-

```
<?php

namespace LR\Adminsalesgrid\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use LR\Adminsalesgrid\Model\Lr;
use \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $Custommodel;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        Lr $Custommodel
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->Custommodel = $Custommodel;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();

        if ($data) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');

            if ($id) {
                $this->Custommodel->load($id);
            }

            $this->Custommodel->setData($data);

            try {
                $this->Custommodel->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The data has been saved.'));
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
                $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());

                return $resultRedirect;
            }catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the data.'));
            }

            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

Please advice me what is actually problem.

**`THANKS.`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Try code**

```
<?php

namespace LR\Adminsalesgrid\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use LR\Adminsalesgrid\Model\Lr;
use \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Save extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $Custommodel;

    public function __construct(
        Action\Context $context,
        Lr $Custommodel
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->Custommodel = $Custommodel;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        if ($data) {
            $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
            if ($id) {
                $this->Custommodel->load($id);
            }
            $this->Custommodel->setData($data);
            try {
                $this->Custommodel->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('The data has been saved.'));
                //$resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
                $order_id = 2; // add your order id here
                $order_url = $this->getUrl("sales/order/view/order_id/".$order_id);
                $resultRedirect->setUrl($order_url);
                return $resultRedirect;
            }catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->messageManager->addException($e, __('Something went wrong while saving the data.'));
            }
            return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/edit', ['id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')]);
        }
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You***

Comment: please check and update me on above answer.

Comment: Hello noob here, Is that applicable on Magento 2.4 as well?

Comment: Yes @DimitriosDesyllas

Answer (score 1):

**$this->_redirect->getRefererUrl()** this means refer to the previous url which is the custom edit page url. So, It will not redirect to the order view page.

You have to send the **order_id** to save action function and create the order view url to redirect. **getRegereeUrl()** will not redirect to order view page.

Comment: Hy, I want to custom form save after back order view page. Thanks.

Comment: hello @Ritesh Santra how to create Please share with me code