# How do we get the total price to change dynamically with quantity?

Tags: magento2, price, qty

> If I change the Quantity for a product in product view page, the price has to change automatically. How can it be achieved?

**Please help me to do this.**

**CODE:-**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) :?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()) :?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Quantity')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <span id="dec" class="btn btn-info-minus">-</span>
                <input type="number"
                   name="qty"
                   id="qty"
                   min="0"
                   value="<?= $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                   class="input-text qty"
                   data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                   />
                <span id="inc" class="btn btn-info-plus">+</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="product-add-info">
            <?php 
            //echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('product-page-delivery')->toHtml();
            echo $_product->getData('delivery_info');

            ?>

            <?php //echo $block->getChildHtml('product.info.price');?>
            <?php //echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\HelloWorld')->setTemplate('Mageplaza_HelloWorld::helloworld.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
            <?php 
                $arguments = [];
                $priceType = \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE;
                $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default');
                $arguments['zone'] = \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render::ZONE_ITEM_LIST;
                $price = '';
                if($priceRender) {
                    $price = $priceRender->render($priceType, $_product, $arguments);
                }
                 echo $price;
            ?>
             <span id="test"></span>

            <div class="actions">
                <button type="submit"
                        title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($buttonTitle) ?>"
                        class="action primary tocart"
                        id="product-addtocart-button" disabled>
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($buttonTitle) ?></span>
                </button>
                <?php //echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
<script>
    require(['jquery'],
    function ($) {
        jQuery('#inc').on('click',function(){
            var $qty=$(this).closest('.box-tocart').find('.input-text');
            var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
            if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                $qty.val(currentVal + 1);
            }
        });
        jQuery('#dec').on('click',function(){
            var $qty=$(this).closest('.box-tocart').find('.input-text');
            var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 1) {
                $qty.val(currentVal - 1);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    require(['jquery'],
    function ($) {
    var price = $(".price-wrapper.price-including-tax span.price").html();
    // var price=$("#price").val();
    jQuery("#qty").on("change",function(){
    qty=$("#qty").val();
    alert(price);
    alert(qty);
    var total_price=price*qty;
    alert(total_price);
    jQuery("#test").html(total_price);
    alert(total_price);

}) 
});   
</script>
```

[image: Feature Explanation Image]

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Check my update question.i have add code

Comment: where you put this file and you use default price box or custom price box ?

Comment: Above code is addtocart.phtml file code

Comment: please check and update me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Try this code**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) :?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()) :?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Quantity')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <span id="dec" class="btn btn-info-minus">-</span>
                <input type="number"
                   name="qty"
                   id="qty"
                   min="0"
                   value="<?= $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                   class="input-text qty"
                   data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                   />
                <span id="inc" class="btn btn-info-plus">+</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="product-add-info">

            <div class="actions">
                <button type="submit"
                        title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($buttonTitle) ?>"
                        class="action primary tocart"
                        id="product-addtocart-button" disabled>
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($buttonTitle) ?></span>
                </button>
                <?php //echo $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>

<?php

$prd_price = $_product->getPrice();

?>
<script>
    require(['jquery'],
    function ($) {
        jQuery('#inc').on('click',function(){
            var $qty = jQuery(this).closest('.box-tocart').find('.input-text');
            var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
            if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
                $qty.val(currentVal + 1);
                var input_qty = <?php echo $prd_price; ?> * (currentVal + 1);
                price_show = parseFloat(input_qty).toFixed(2);
                var price_get = jQuery(".product-info-main .price-box.price-final_price span.price").text();
                var new_sub_text = price_get.replace(/\d+/g, '');
                new_sub_text = new_sub_text.replace(".", '');
                jQuery(".product-info-main .price-box.price-final_price span.price").text(new_sub_text+price_show);
            }
        });
        jQuery('#dec').on('click',function(){
            var $qty = jQuery(this).closest('.box-tocart').find('.input-text');
            var currentVal = parseInt($qty.val());
            if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 1) {
                $qty.val(currentVal - 1);
                var input_qty = <?php echo $prd_price; ?> * (currentVal - 1);
                price_show = parseFloat(input_qty).toFixed(2);
                var price_get = jQuery(".product-info-main .price-box.price-final_price span.price").text();
                var new_sub_text = price_get.replace(/\d+/g, '');
                new_sub_text = new_sub_text.replace(".", '');
                jQuery(".product-info-main .price-box.price-final_price span.price").text(new_sub_text+price_show);
            }

        });


    });
</script>
```

Comment: I will check and update you. thank you

Comment: i have check your code but is it not working properly. check this image :- https://prnt.sc/ufylcj @Msquare

Comment: there is one line issue this line  var input_qty = <?php echo $prd_price; ?> * (currentVal - 1); don't worry i update my answer please check it and update me.

Comment: @MohitPatel Please check and update me and you also update me on this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/321464/82670

Comment: Hello @Msquare i have your update code all is working fine but one issue found.i have increase or de-crease button click currency symbol is increase. :-  https://prnt.sc/ug19g3

Comment: @MohitPatel code is running perfectly. please check after fulsh caches.

Comment: for other product you need to pass product price like other way which multiple with qty. becuse if config product then you need to get current selected option product price and for other try to get price and set in this  $prd_price = $_product->getPrice();